# $ sign undefined error in javascript/vue.js page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on the javascript/vue.js page [at this link](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lex-web-ui/blob/master/lex-web-ui/src/store/index.js). I added this code to the file above:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  myIP();
});

function myIP() {
  $.getJSON("//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
    // after succesful ajax response call myCallback with data.ip
    myCallback(data.ip); 
  });
}

function myCallback(theIP) {
// do your stuff here
   console.log("Data.ip:", theIP);
   configDefault.lex.sessionAttributes.ip = theIP;
   //console.log("ConfigDefault:", configDefault);
};
```

When I load the webpage I see `$ sign undefined` error. I then added `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` but then I started getting error

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (34:0)

  32 | 
  33 | 
> 34 | <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     | ^
  35 | 
  36 | // TODO turn this into a class
```

One thing I noticed that there is no `<head>` section in the file at the above link and most of the solutions shown on SO mentioned to put the jQuery link in `<head>` section.

What do I need to do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The file you linked to is a JavaScript file, identified by the `.js` extension. JavaScript files do not have a `<head>` section, these are for HTML files, with the extension `.html`. You would need to find the HTML file that the JavaScript file is linked to and add:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

to that, in it's head section. jQuery will then work in the JavaScript file.